# Insert new rows, continue existing rowset row_number count

Tags: azure, u-sql

I'm attempting to perform some sort of upsert operation in U-SQL where I pull data every day from a file, and compare it with yesterdays data which is stored in a table in Data Lake Storage.

I have created an ID column in the table in DL using row_number(), and it is this "counter" I wish to continue when appending new rows to the old dataset. E.g. 
Last inserted row in DL table could look like this:

```
ID | Column1    | Column2
---+------------+---------
10 | SomeValue  |    1
```

I want the next rows to have the following ascending ids

```
11 | SomeValue  |   1 
12 | SomeValue  |   1
```

How would I go about making sure that the next X rows continues the ID count incrementally such that the next rows each increases the ID column by 1 more than the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` then add it to the the max value from the original table (ie using `CROSS JOIN` and `MAX`).  A simple demo of the technique:

```
DECLARE @outputFile string = @"\output\output.csv";

@originalInput =
    SELECT *
    FROM ( VALUES
        ( 10, "SomeValue 1", 1 )
        ) AS x ( id, column1, column2 );


@newInput =
    SELECT *
    FROM ( VALUES
        ( "SomeValue 2", 2 ),
        ( "SomeValue 3", 3 )
        ) AS x ( column1, column2 );


@output =
    SELECT id, column1, column2
    FROM @originalInput

    UNION ALL

    SELECT (int)(x.id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER()) AS id, column1, column2
    FROM @newInput
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM @originalInput ) AS x;


OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true);
```

My results:

[image: Results]

You will have to be careful if the original table is empty and add some additional conditions / null checks but I'll leave that up to you.